# Prolog: Rules evaluating in an unexpected order

Tags: list, prolog, rule

I am currently working on a Prolog program to remove duplicates from a list.

Here is my code:

```
makeset([First], [First]). % if only one item in list, the solution is itself.
makeset([First, Second], [First, Second]) :-
   dif(First, Second).
makeset([First, Second], [First]) :-
    First = Second.
% if more than two items in list
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :-
   member(First, Tail),
   makeset(Tail, FinalList).
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :-
   not(member(First, Tail)),
   makeset(Tail, [First |FinalList]).
```

However, when I try this on a list with more than two items in it, it just returns false. I ran a trace, and found that it keeps using the last two rules even when it gets down to two items in the list. Why is this?

Example query: `makeset([3, 2, 4, 5, 1], X).`
I get back false, but it keeps using the last rule for every evaluation.

**Edit:**
I changed the rules to the following, and it still will not evaluate properly, so the issue has to be with the last rule.

```
makeset([First], FinalList) :- 
 FinalList = [First]. % if only one item in list, the solution is itself.
makeset([First, Second], FinalList) :- 
 not(First = Second), FinalList = [First, Second].
makeset([First, Second], FinalList) :- 
 First = Second, FinalList = [First].
% if more than two items in list
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :- 
 member(First, Tail), makeset(Tail, FinalList).
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :- 
 not(member(First, Tail)), makeset(Tail, [First |FinalList]).
```

How might I fix the final rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
makeset([First | Tail], [First | FinalList]) :- 
 not(member(First, Tail)), makeset(Tail, FinalList).
```

You should not make `First` part of the input to `makeset`, that prevents the earlier rules from matching. You should only add `First` to the list after `FinalList` is unified using the `makeset` predicate.

Your solution also does not handle the case when the input list is empty.

Comment: Perfect, that works great. I will also handle the empty list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Purify your code!

First off. It seems you are sticking to the pure side of this world. Of course, you are using `dif/2`! In contrast to its procedural counterpart its ugly sibling `(\=)/2` which means *not unifiable at this point in time, but maybe later, or never, don't ask me*, the `dif/2` predicate has a pure declarative meaning. It means (syntactic or theory free) inequality. And this will not only buy you karma and indulgences. No, it can even help you to debug your program. In fact, we can use Prolog to help us find the problems in your program — if only your code is pure enough! So first, let's purify your code, and then we can debug it.

The only thing that is not OK in your code, is `not(member(First, Tail))`. I will replace it by `maplist(dif(First),Tail)`.  Now we have a pure program. It fails, as it did before. The first thing might be to reduce the size of your list. Do you really want to go through that chore? Here is a simpler method that only works in pure Prolog programs. I will ask:

> Show me for all lists imaginable, what their set would be.

Right, **all lists**. Not one will be left behind.

### Ask Prolog!

```
?- length(L,I), makeset(L, X).
   L = [_A], I = 1, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_B], I = 2, X = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A], I = 2, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A], I = 2, X = [_A]
;  ... .
```

That is bad enough to start with! First, there is no solution for `I = 0`. Let's add the fact `makeset([], [])` and then there is this redundancy for `I = 2`. You can remove the rule `makeset([First, Second], [First]) :- First = Second.` Now, let's ask again the query:

```
?- length(L,I), makeset(L, X).
   L = [_A], I = 1, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_B], I = 2, X = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A], I = 2, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A], I = 2, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_B], I = 3, X = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A,_A], I = 3, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A], I = 3, X = [_A]
;  L = [_B,_A,_B], I = 3, X = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A,_A], I = 3, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A], I = 3, X = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_B], I = 4, X = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  ... .
```

All answers for `I in 0..2` seem now perfect. They contain all the lists imaginable. All of them. Note that in one answer there is again the `dif/2` occurring, ensuring that the elements are different.

For `I = 3` things get more complex. Some observations:

- there is no answer for `X = [_,_,_]`. Bug found! In fact, minimal bug found!
- there is a redundant answer for `L = [_A,_A,_A]`

We can reduce the first problem to a single goal:

```
?- L = [_,_,_], L = X, makeset(L, X).
   false.
```

There should be an answer. We can now apply another strategy:

### Generalize your code

Evidently the definition of `makeset/2` is too specialized. I will now try to generalize it to better localize the error. To this end, add the following into your program:

```
:- op(950,fy, [*]).

*_.
```

In this manner we can add `*` in front of a goal to remove it. We could use comments for that, too, but this is a cleaner method. So what I do now is to systematically add `*`, and then see if the goal still fails. Further, I renamed some variables to new names (`_x`) which is tantamount to a further generalization. After some trying, I end up with:

```
:- op(950,fy, [*]).
*_.

makeset([], []).
makeset([First], [_xFirst]).
makeset([First, Second], [_xFirst, _xSecond]) :-
   * dif(First, Second).
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :-
   * member(First, Tail),
   makeset(Tail, FinalList).
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :-
   * maplist(dif(First),Tail),
   makeset(Tail, [_xFirst |FinalList]).

?- L = [_,_,_], L = X, makeset(L, X).
   false.
```

In this program, the actual elements are no longer of relevance. Thus it is only the length of the lists! So the problem must have to do with the way how the length is handled. The last rule only applies, if there is a solution with the second argument being a longer list. Which can't be. So the problem is the last rule. The list should occur rather in the head.

Now, new redundancies appear. The final definition reads:

```
makeset([], []).
makeset([First | Tail], FinalList) :-
   member(First, Tail),
   makeset(Tail, FinalList).
makeset([First | Tail], [First|FinalList]) :-
   maplist(dif(First),Tail),
   makeset(Tail, FinalList).
```

There are smarter ways to express this `member`/`maplist dif` dichotomy. But I will leave it like that...

Answer (score 1):

In the last rule, you move elements from first list to second.
Then you prevent matching the top rules.

Note: dif/2 it's a powerful but complex predicate. Do you effectively need its power ?

Comment: I started using dif because using not (first = second) didn't seem to work properly.

Comment: `First \= Second` will work, as well as `not(First = Second)`, albeit it's usually written `\+(First = Second)`. This make a difference only when you are inspecting lists containing variables.

Comment: I changed the first few rules, but it is still not matching, so I have updated the question to ask how the final rule should be changed. Thanks.